# Why does my button act weird in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

When I press `button1` my scene does not change, and it says that `button2` was pressed. Why is this?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;
    Button button, button2;
    Scene scene, scene2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("title");

        // label 1
        Label label1 = new Label("This is scene 1");

        // button 1
        button = new Button("Go to scene 2");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            window.setScene(scene2);
            System.out.println("button 1 pressed");
        });

        // layout 1
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(label1, button);
        scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 500);

        // label 2
        Label label2 = new Label("This is scene 2");

        // button 2
        button2 = new Button("go to scene 1");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            window.setScene(scene);
            System.out.println("button 2 pressed");
        });

        // layout 2
        StackPane layout2 = new StackPane();
        layout2.getChildren().addAll(label2, button2);
        scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 200, 500);

        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Just add 2: instead of changing the `onAction` handler of the first button, set the one for the second button: `button2.setOnAction(e -> {
        window.setScene(scene);
        System.out.println("button 2 pressed");
    });`

Comment: @fabian When `button2` is pressed, change scene to `scene` and print out `button 2 pressed`. Is this not what is says? I want the button1 to take me to scene 2 and I want button2 to take me to scene1

Comment: You call `button.setOnAction` however, even for the second time you want to set a `onAction` handler.

Comment: Doing like that didnt solve it though!

Comment: I've just tested it. By replacing the second `button.setOnAction` with `button2.setOnAction` (the one after the `// button 2` comment) it switches the `Scene`s. If you wonder why you do not see the `Label`s: This is caused by the fact that both elements are placed on top of each other by the `StackPane`, since both are centered. Furthermore the `Button`s are drawn above the `Label`s since they have a higher child index.

Comment: @fabian Sorry, I misunderstood you..! Yes, by changeing it to `button2` instead worked like a charm, thx! Alright I didnt know that about the labels.  I will see if I can figure out how to properly arrange them. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When you define button 2, your 'setOnAction' is for button (not button2). So to get it to work correctly change button.setOnAction for button2 to button2.setOnAction. Then it will work.

Some pointers that may help you in future: if you debug your program rather than run and set a breakpoint at window.setScene(scene2); and another one at window.setScene(scene); then you would have found that when you press button, execution stops at window.setScene(scene);

In other words, the wrong action handler was called when button1 was pressed. And there is your answer.

Also if you are trying to test two scenes like this, make one different from the other e.g. scene1 = new Scene(layout, 200, 500); and scene2 = new Scene(layout, 500, 200); That way it's more obvious which one you're looking at.